# How can you read different sized bit values from a file?

Tags: c++, file, fread

I'm reading a bunch of bit values from a text file which are in binary from because I stored them using `fwrite`. The problem is that the first value in the file is 5 bytes in size and the next 4800 values are 2 bytes in size. So when I try to cycle through the file and read the values it will give me the wrong results because my program does not know that it should take 5 bytes the first time and then 2 bytes the remaining 4800 times.

Here is how I'm cycling through the file:

```
long lSize;
unsigned short * buffer;
size_t result;

pFile = fOpen("dataValues.txt", "rb");

lSize = ftell(pFile);

buffer = (unsigned short *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned short)*lSize);    
size_t count = lSize/sizeof(short);



for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
   result = fread(buffer+i, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, pFile);
   print("%u\n", buffer[i]);
 }
```

I'm pretty sure I'm going to need to change my `fread` statement because the first value is of type `time_t` so I'll probably need a statement that looks like this:

```
result = fread(buffer+i, sizeof(time_t), 1, pFile);
```

However, this did not work work when I tried it and I think it's because I am not changing the starting position properly. I think that while I do read 5 bytes worth of data, I don't move the starting position enough.

Does anyone here have a good understanding of `fread`? Can you please let me know what I can change to make my program accomplish what I need.

**EDIT:**

This is how I'm writing to the file.

```
fwrite(&timer, sizeof(timer), 1, pFile);
fwrite(ptr, sizeof(unsigned short), rawData.size(), pFile);
```

**EDIT2:**

I tried to read the file using `ifstream`

```
int main()
{
    time_t x;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("binaryValues.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
    infile.read((char *) &x, sizeof(x));
    return 0;
}
```

However, now it doesn't compile and just give me a bunch of `undefined reference to` errors to code that I don't even have written.

Comment: It may be useful to post the code you used to store the data. Also are you reading this file from a different machine that wrote it?

Comment: No same machine and I've added the `fwrite` code. It's pretty standard. I'm just taking a some values from a QVector and writing them to a file.

Comment: The code used to store the data appears to be C++? So this should be tagged C++?

Comment: 1) Is the file opened in binary or text mode.  (Post the `fopen()` call.)  2) What is the file's length as reported by the OS?  3) "first value in the file is 5 bytes in size" and `sizeof(timer)` as 5 is just about unbelievable.  Report `printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(timer));`

Comment: I've added my `fopen()` call and I the size of `time_t` is reported as 4. The length of the file is variable and it should me stored in the `lSize` variable.

Comment: `ftell` only gives you the size of the file if you seek to the end first.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The code worked find when I only had a bunch of 2 bytes values in there so I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Just because it doesn't crash doesn't make it correct.  If count is zero then your for loop won't execute at all.

Comment: simplest fix.   Software cannot read your mind.   So you have to write the software to take all the details into account.  I.E. the software must be told/written such that it reads the first line as 5 entities and all following lines as 2 entities.

Comment: I hope you realize that `ifstream` is a class in C++, not in C.  (they are really two different languages) and a C compiler will not compile a C++ program.

Comment: when asking about a runtime problem, post code that is short, cleanly compiles and still shows the problem. Also post the actual input, the actual output and the expected output.  when asking about a compile time problem, post the code, post the compile command line, post the error message(s)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem:

```
uint8_t five_byte_buffer[5];
uint8_t two_byte_buffer[2];
//...
ifstream my_file(/*...*/);
my_file.read(&five_byte_buffer[0], 5);
my_file.read(&two_byte_buffer[0], 2);
```

So, what is your specific issue?

**Edit 1: Reading in a loop**

```
while (my_file.read(&five_byte_buffer[0], 5))
{
  my_file.read(&two_byte_buffer[0], 5);
  Process_Data();
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your post what are those two arrays for? And why are you doing `my_file.read`? I don't program in C++ so sorry if I'm being stupid right now.

Comment: Your post said you need to read in 5 bytes and then 2 bytes.  The buffers hold the data that you read.

Comment: The `my_file.read` is the C++ method for reading unprocessed data from a stream, in this case, the `my_file` stream.

Comment: Sorry, but you originally had C++ tags.

Comment: I am writing this in C++. The problem is I'm not just reading a single 5 byte value and then a single 2 byte value. I'm doing it over and over again.

Comment: If you have to do something "over and over again", sounds like you need a loop.  See my edit.

Comment: I tried to do what you said but it's giving me errors. Did I do it correctly or is the problem elsewhere?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you dynamically allocate the buffer?  C++ is not Java or C# so you don't need to do that. (You don't need to do it in C either).

Comment: What are you referring to? The old set of code that uses `fread` or the new code that uses `fstream`? I'm just following the online guides that are out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Streams are byte, almost always octet (8 bit byte) oriented.

You can easily enough build a bit-oriented stream on top of that. You just keep a few bytes in a buffer and keep track of which bit is current. Watch out for getting the last few bits, and attempts to mix byte access with bit access.

Untested but this is the general idea.

```
  struct bitstream
  {
      unsigned long long rack;  // 64 bits rack
      FILE *fp;                 // file opened for reading
      int rackpos;              // 0 - 63, poisition of bits read.
  }

  int getbits(struct bitstream *bs, int Nbits)
  {
     unsigned long long mask = 0x8000 0000 0000 0000;
     int answer = 0;

     while(bs->rackpos > 8)
     {
        bs->rack <<= 8;
        bs->rack |= fgetc(bs->fp);
        bs->rackpos -= 8;
     }
     mask >>= bs->rackpos;
     for(i=0;i<Nbits;i++)
     {
        answer <<= 1;
        answer |= bs->rack & mask;
        mask >>= 1;
     }
     bs->rackpos += Nbits;

     return answer;
  }
```

You need to decide how you know when the stream is terminated. As is you'll corrupt the last few bits with the EOF read by fgetc().

Comment: Sorry but I'm a total C++ noob, can you explain what you mean? Is there still a way for me to accomplish what I need? Like is there no way that I can distinguish a `time_t` value from an `unsigned_short` value?